# Error when trying to query the json, but I always get the same error ERROR - 'meta'

Tags: python, json, python-requests, response, python-requests-json

```
{
"droplets": [],
"links": {},
"meta": {
"total": 3
}
```

I would like to receive this 'total: 3', through json, I tried this way

```
        totals = droplet_response.json()
        tt = totals['meta']['total']
```

and he returned this to me

```
ERROR - 'meta'
```

Comment: Is that what `droplets_response.json()` actually looks like?

Comment: yes, inside droplets_response.json() this appears, I just want the "'total': 3"

Comment: Is it possible to show a minimal example that shows the code that can reproduce this? And what does `tt` look like if you do a `print(tt)` on it? Right now, from just glancing at it, it seems like it should work, though I don’t know what library you’re using so I don’t know what `json()` should look like from the response.

Comment: ***ERROR - unhashable type: 'set'***

Comment: you are missing a `}` in the json posted at the top. Show us `print(totals)`